# Best practices when designing an interactive dashboard Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working towards designing an interactive menu. The main idea is a dashboard with some buttons within (see picture for example). After an user clicks on the picture, the app would render a similar dashboard, but with different buttons.

The flow of the dashboard would have depth 3 => Main categories => sub categories => sub sub categories.

My question here is, what is the best practice to avoid the user from generating a lot of screens within the app (by clicking a lot of buttons)? Does flutter automatically take care of this? I guess my main concern is, what could go wrong in terms of designing something like this in terms of cell phone using too much power to render the app?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My humble approach toward this is to create only one view (screen) and use a state management package to update the view. I'm familiar with [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc).

In your state you would define an int to keep track of the menu level:

- menuLevel == 0: main memu
- menuLevel == 1: sub menu
- menuLevel == 2: sub sub menu

Then in your view's BlocBuilder you update the view based on the menuLevel state property.

This answer might sound a bit vag because it assumes that you are familiar with state management in Flutter. In particular with flutter_bloc. If not, I strongly recommend you learn a bit more about state management as it will save you time and help you better tackle this kind of situation in an efficient manner.

Comment: Sounds good! Do you have any recommended readings for state management? thank you! :)

Comment: This [one](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) is the most complete and the most comprehensive I have ever found :)